# Java Regex to accept anything but not angle brackets

Tags: java, regex

I want a regex to be used in Java which can contain any special characters, alphabets or numbers but not **<**  OR  **>** (angle brackets).

I found this, `^[\<>]*`
but it gives

> Invalid escape sequence

when used in my code.

Please help.

Comment: You don't have to escape `<>`

Comment: By *"alphabets or numbers"* did you mean "letters or digits"? Is whitespaces and control characters considered *"special characters"*?

Comment: @AvinashRaj - [^<>]* worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 String regex="[^<>]*";
        Pattern p= Pattern.compile(regex);
        if(p.matcher("your input string").matches()){
            // place for your logic
        }
```

Comment: Easier for one match: `if ("your input string".matches("[^<>]*")) { //your logic }`